# Rewrite SQL query in other form without UNION

Tags: sql, hql

Can anyone help me with rewriting this query without `UNION`?

I need this query without `UNION` to use in HQL. Is there any other way how to join two selects like this?

My point is that I need to join results from these two queries from the same table in one result. Thanks!

```
SELECT tab.name AS name FROM Table tab 
WHERE tab.name LIKE '%abc%' 
UNION 
SELECT TO_CHAR(tab.id) AS name FROM Table tab 
WHERE  tab.id = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be equivalent:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN tab.id = 5 THEN TO_CHAR(tab.id)
            ELSE tab.name 
        END AS name 
FROM Table tab 
WHERE tab.name LIKE '%abc%' 
OR tab.id = 5
```

Comment: unless there is a record where `name LIKE '%abc%' and id = 5`; in which case the rewrite omits the name while the original includes it.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger yeah, I was about to add that disclaimer to my answer, but now I rather let it as is, and upvoting your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #TABLE(NAME)
SELECT tab.NAME AS NAME
FROM   table tab
WHERE  tab.NAME LIKE '%abc%'

INSERT INTO #TABLE(NAME)
SELECT TO_CHAR(tab.id) AS NAME
FROM   table tab
WHERE  tab.id = 5

SELECT NAME
FROM   #TABLE
```

Comment: From the [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) documentation I found online, I'm not seeing support for temporary tables as used in your answer.